# Cannot access translate value in Class files (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locale

I am using locale file to save the English text, and I am using these text in controller by calling it like `t(:user_created_message)`.

But when I moved my logic to a class file under `/lib/classes/users/user.rb` and tried to access the translate, it shows error like `undefined method t for Users::User`

How should I load the translate variable when calling from custom classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I18n.t :user_created_message
```

Please read the documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html), the method you're using only works inside the views.